# Berkley DB woefully outdated in repos

Tags: berkeleydb

Why is the repo seemingly locked at version 5.3 of Berkley DB when current versions are well past 12?

https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/berkeleydb/html/changelog_6_0.html

> New Features in 6.0.19 Fixed bugs when attempting to open non-DB files
>   as if they were databases. If encryption was active, an assertion
>   failure would occur. If encryption was not active, the error message
>   "BDB0178 Encrypted database: no encryption flag" would incorrectly
>   imply that a password was required. [#21408]

I need to get to at least version 6.0.19 to do some work with Gnu COBOL. I don't want to have the problems someone else had with Ubuntu install 5.3 libraries then trying to install a higher version.

Is there a PPA if the official repos are going to be many years out of date?

No, this isn't a duplicate.This also isn't just one package. You can't reliably just install the newer version when things have been built against the incredibly outdated 5.3. There are other sites on the Web talking about all of the issues resulting from that. You might get "some" things to work, but not all.

[image]

That image isn't even all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: You didn't provide the package name you're complaining about (I would have looked up to see if it's been reported), but package maintainers are busy as not many step up to help, and if they're not notified by end-users of updates being available, they can be missed, so reporting a bug can alert them they need to re-package. Have you reported it?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: It's way more than just one package.

Answer (score 1):

Download Berkeley DB 18.1 from the [official Oracle webpage](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb-downloads.html). You will be required to create an Oracle Account in order to download this file.

[image: Oracle Account sign in]

[image: Create Oracle Account]

Install 
Berkeley DB 18.1.32.tar.gz by following the instructions at [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/).

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: According to what I've found you have to un-install all things in Ubuntu built against 5.3 before installing the latest.

Comment: I wish I could include the screen shot for Oracle account creation. __That's__ a severe invasion of privacy.

Comment: I don't need to see it. I can imagine it from Microsoft Azure Notebooks.

Comment: cd build_unix ; 
../dist/configure ; 
make ; 
sudo make install
```